# How to get meaningful coordinates when a plot is embedded in GraphicsGrid/Column

Tags: graphics, date-and-time, coordinate

This code produces a `DateListPlot` such that when I select Get Coordinates, hovering over a point with the mouse will generate a tooltip displaying the timestamp for that point as well as the associated value.

```
DateListPlot[pointsETHtehran[[;; 400]], 
 PlotRange -> {{{2020, 1, 2, 4, 0, 0.}, {2020, 1, 3, 8, 0, 0.}}, 
   Automatic}, 
 CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"DisplayFunction" -> 
    MapAt[DateString, 1]}]
```

This produces an example tooltip of the format

```
{Thu 2 Jan 2020 07:31:49 100.166}
```

The problem arises when I embed 2 such plots in a `GraphicsColumn` command in order to be able to compare the aligned graphs.

```
GraphicsColumn[{DateListPlot[pointsETHtehran[[;; 400]], 
   PlotRange -> {{{2020, 1, 2, 4, 0, 0.}, {2020, 1, 3, 8, 0, 0.}}, 
     Automatic}], 
  DateListPlot[pointsRTHtehran[[;; 340]], 
   PlotRange -> {{{2020, 1, 2, 4, 0, 0.}, {2020, 1, 3, 8, 0, 0.}}, 
     Automatic}]}, 
 CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"DisplayFunction" -> 
    MapAt[DateString, 1]}]
```

This produces an example tooltip like

```
{Mon 1 Jan 1900 00:01:26, -97.9167}
```

These points lie outside of the domain of the data.
What appears to be happening is that the coordinates are being returned as pixel positions rather than in terms of the data domain. (This can be confirmed by removing the specification for the `DisplayFunction` above.)

I tried moving the `CoordinatesToolOptions` specification to within the `DateListPlot` function itself but this makes things worse in that the `DisplayFunction` is no longer recognized and only raw pixel coordinates are returned.

Is there any way of forcing `GraphicsColumn` to return the coordinates expressed in the appropriate space?

thanks

Comment: Not really a solution but a quick workaround is to specify `CoordinatesToolOptions` within `DateListPlot` and then use `Column` instead of `GraphicsColumn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use [`ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid), which will preserve any settings for `CoordinatesToolOptions`:

```
data = {{DateObject[{2016, 10, 1}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 10}, {DateObject[{2016, 10, 15}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 17}, {DateObject[{2016, 10, 30}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 15}, {DateObject[{2016, 11, 20}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 20}};
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][
 {
  {DateListPlot[data, CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"DisplayFunction" -> MapAt[DateString, 1]}]},
  {DateListPlot[data]}
  },
 Spacings -> 30
 ]
```

[image]

Please note that the current version of `PlotGrid` has a small bug that causes the text "False" to appear above `DateListPlot` objects. To work around this until the fixed version is available, the easiest solution is to add the setting `"ShowFrameLabels" -> Directive[Top -> None]` to forcefully hide the top frame ticks of all plots (hence removing the spurious `False`)

Comment: Works beautifully. Thanks for putting in the effort to create this.